# How do I go about solving this block diagram?

Tags: control-system

I've tried moving the feedback loops, but I don't know which ones to move. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: what happened when you moved them? ... how did you decide that you moved the wrong ones?

Comment: I know its wrong because the final answer looked really weird to what normally block diagram reduction answers look like.

Comment: please include your final answer in your post

Comment: I haven't arrived at any conclusive answer yet. sorry. What I mentioned earlier was for another homework. I got confused sorry again

Comment: i am trying to keep your question from getting closed ... you have to do work at solving your homework assignment ... your attempt has to be presented in your post ... that way, people can examine your work to detemine where you require help and offer suggestions that may guide you to arrive at a correct solution

Comment: @Ktrix Please edit your question so it includes an attempt, and as a hint, you need to break the loop and do some algebraic substitution OR find simplification methods

Comment: okay ill clear my work and start attempting again and update the thread

Comment: To begin your work, try first reducing the last little loop (with 1/3s)... It is the easy part.

Comment: It's a quite nasty exercise but you should *at least* say way you are trying to accomplish (I guess put it into the normal feeback form for analysis)

Comment: @Ktrix you should consider formally accepting an answer.

Answer (score 7):

Just re-arrange things to get rid of the interlocked feedback loops. Here's the first interlocked loop solved (I'd made a mistake yesterday that I'm correcting today): -

[image]

OK, there's still some work to do but, it should be reasonably straightforward (because there will be 4 **non-interlocked** cascaded functional sub-blocks that can be dealt with individually).

In case there's any further doubts, I've used micro-cap to solve this part (ignoring the orange feedback): -

[image]

The "op-amp" like symbols (X4, X5 and X8) are integrators with a gain of 0.5 i.e. they represent the Laplace term \$\frac{0.5}{s}\$ or \$\frac{1}{2s}\$ as shown in the first blue blocks above.

Amplitude Bode plot: -

[image]

And, once again, apologies for yesterday's stupid mistake. So, if you want to plod through this problem, consider following this fairly math-free route: -

[image]

I'll leave it to someone else to do the final block diagram touches and then the algebra!

Oh, what the hell, I'm almost there: -

[image]

Comment: Unless I made a mistake, always possible, have you checked the transfer functions of the two schemas ? I do not find the same thing.

Comment: @Antonio51 what is it that you don't agree with? Be specific please.

Comment: I did not do this type of exercices in my young time. So I made a simulation with microcap with Laplace functions and control as usual I do with equations into Maple. Results transfer functions are not the same. Unless I am mistaken.

Comment: Maybe you are mistaken somewhere. Maybe you should begin a new question showing what you did and explain how the two block diagrams in my answer are not the same when simulated in microcap. BTW - microcap is a very, very good choice and beats LTspice hands down. Maybe you should look at what I did in solving the second block diagram from the first. I don't see a flaw but, it's easy to overlook stuff.

Comment: That's why I try to verify by at least two different and uncorrelated means ...

Comment: @Antonio51 your final formula is the same as mine (in block diagram form) so something is probably wrong in your side-by-side comparison.

Comment: Right. I apply the same method for the two pictures. But my answers for the first original picture are also the "same" (4 th order for the function, low pass filter) with Microcap12 and Maple? The difference in curves is because number of points in Maple are too low.

Comment: I have no idea where you are going with this. If you want resolution raise a brand new question.

Comment: Please, Can you just verify my answer ?

Comment: @Antonio51 I've been giving this some thought and I have made an error in my answer that I'm going to correct shortly.

Comment: No worries, Andy. We are not perfect. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here what I tried about displacement of blok function ...Particular case.

First right circuit in the picture is original

Second is microcap12 equivalent with Laplace functions

Third is circuit with displacement of right block to the left

Quarter is circuit with displacement of right block to the right

At left, the three transfert functions are superposed -> equivalent.

[image]