# Block diagram reduction (input and output transfer function)

Tags: block-diagram

I need guidance for this block diagram reduction problem. Not answers but thorough guidance, thank you!
it involves solving the input and output transfer function

[image: block diagram]

Comment: I just use KCL and stuff like this just falls out. There are a lot of rules for block diagram reduction. But I hate memorizing such things when there already exists a simple and more broadly useful tool than having to learn and retain a series of reduction rules. Just as I prefer using KCL rather than memorizing a bunch of Thevenin equivalents. More to your point, though: There are countless videos and web pages on the topic of reduction rules. Do you know how to use any of them on this case? Any at all? Or does nothing at all come to mind here?

Comment: Please ask a specific question and present a solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

> *I need guidance for this block diagram reduction problem. Not answers
> but thorough guidance*

Here are a couple of starting pointers: -

[image]

Then try this: -

[image]

Is the enough guidance for you to solve the rest of the problem?

[Here's another example](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/575481/how-do-i-go-about-solving-this-block-diagram/575528#575528)

This is pretty useful too: -

[image]